# What is the difference between write_all and flush in io::Write trait?

Tags: rust

I am talking about the `std::io::Write`. The definition `flush` reads like basically exactly the same as the definition of the `write_all` function.

I have attempted understanding the difference by checking a couple popular `Write` implementing libraries like `TcpStream` but typically I see they just return `Ok(())` without doing anything.

Is it okay to just not implement `flush` if we aren't dealing with some underlying system call for flushing some internal buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) ensures that all data in the passed buffer is consumed (whereas [`write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write) may consume only part of the data). To this effect, `write_all` will retry automatically until the whole data has been consumed (or an unrecoverable error occurs).

However this does not guarantee that the data has actually been written to disk (or to the underlying medium): it may have been buffered in the program (e.g. in a `BufferedWriter`) or by the OS. [`flush`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) waits until all data that was previously consumed has been written to the underlying medium. This makes sense when writing to disk but may not make sense in other contexts, which is why some implementations of `flush` do nothing.

If you're writing a custom `Write` implementation, you can keep an empty `flush` method if "flushing" doesn't make sense for your target.

Comment: `write_all ensures that all data in the passed buffer is sent to the OS`. I feel "sent to the OS" is a confusing statement when some bytes are copied into e.g. the `BufWriter` buffer. Assuming the buffer still has capacity I'd assume it's nothing but a copy based on `write_to_buffer_unchecked`. It's not really sent anywhere except into this buffer.

Comment: @peterulb edited. Does the new formulation seem clearer?